# RVM quiet install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

How can one do a quieter rvm install, skipping this message:

> - To start using RVM you need to run `source
>     /home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
>     in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
>
> ## ubuntu,
>
> #
>
> ## Thank you for using RVM!
>
> ## We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
>
> #
>
> ## ~Wayne, Michal & team.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this

```
rvm install && echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: The question refers to the installation of rvm itself.  Usually done with
` \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`